# IE7,8,9 not reading media query properly.

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, media-queries

I have this **[page](http://habeshajobs.com/liip.php)** which is actually rendered fine in all browsers, meaning.. when browser is contracted, to show mobile version of the layout, based on `@media` query css settings, but not in IE8, as far as I can check. How do I get around of this problem.

Here is all the code btw:

```
<html>
<head><style>
body{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#a{height:150px; background-color:#ffffff; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;}
#x{min-height:350px; margin-top: 10px; background-color:#CCC;}
#y{min-height:30px; margin-top: 10px; background-color:#CCC;}


@media all and (min-width:700px){

#b{width:100%;  min-height:400px;}
    #sep {
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px;
}
    #x{width:65%; float:left;}
    #y{width:32%; float:right; }
#c{background-color:#656565; height:80px;}
.for-mob{display:none;}
.for-desc{background-color:green;}
}
@media all and (max-width:700px){
.for-mob{background-color:green;}
.for-desc{display:none;}
#b{width:100%; min-height:400px; }
#x{width:100%; display:block; }
#y{width:100%; display:block; }
#c{background-color:#656565; height:100px;}

}
</style></head>
<body>

<div id='a'> <h1>I am header </h1>
</div> 

<div id='b'>
<div id='sep'>

    <div id='x'>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    <h1>I am content </h1>
    </div>
    <div id='y'>
    <h1>I am sidebar </h1>
    </div>
</div> 
</div> 
<div class='for-desc'><h1>If you shrink the browser, I become invisible</h1> </div>
<div class='for-mob'><h1>If you maximize the browser, I become invisible</h1></div>

<div id='c'>
<h1> I am a simple footer </h1>
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: I don't think media queries are supported in IE8 and before btw..

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries => you'll need a javascript solution to use a media query style of display

Comment: Respond.js is your friend here.  (Make sure you read the docs.)

Comment: @RichieHindle thanks, but I added `<script src="respond.min.js"></script>` after the `</style>` and even placed the js file in the same directory, but it not working

Comment: Do you really need IE7 & 8 to be responsive? We just serve the desktop styles to those two browsers regardless. (Nobody's surfing the web on a mobile device with IE7 or 8)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? but, I need IE7 & IE8 to be responsieve @KevinBoucher

Comment: btw, you dont need to bring in another library (respond.js) to do this. thats the easy way, its not the efficient way. split your media queries into different files, give your `link` an ID tag, `onload` get `window.innerWidth`, then use a basic `if` statement to pull back the file for that size, like `document.getElementById('mediaQuery').setAttribute('href','800.css');`.

Comment: @kranzdot: That's why I said "Make sure you read the docs." You'll need to split your CSS into a separate file rather than putting it inline. There may be other reasons it's not working, but it's all clearly explained in the documentation.

Comment: respond.js is your friend here but also use conditional comments to check if ie7 or 8 and then load a special ie.css stylesheet in which to call .ie classes; these override the modern browser calls that aren't being read. A full description here if you need it: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/add-body-class-just-for-ie/

Answer (score 0):

Response.js only creates rules on elements, to emulate the media query use
https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

It would be better to include a specific css only for IE<9 but it is up to you :)