# Floats and Media Queries not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float, media-queries

My site works perfectly in Chrome in FF but IE is ignoring my Media Queries entirely and messing with my float: left elements. The elements are 9 images set up in table (but I'm using floats for responsiveness) of 3 rows and 3 columns. The first row shows up correctly but the second row is messed up, bumping the third photo onto its own row, like this:

PHOTO PHOTO PHOTO
                           PHOTO PHOTO
                                                      PHOTO
PHOTO PHOTO PHOTO

When it should be:

PHOTO PHOTO PHOTO
PHOTO PHOTO PHOTO
PHOTO PHOTO PHOTO

Again, this is ONLY happening in IE, I'm using IE 10 and 11 for testing.

Here's my css:

```
#teambiowrap
{
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
} 

#teambio
{
    width: 28%;
    float: left;
    padding: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.bioimg
{
    width: 99%;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  #teambio {
    float: none;  
    width: 90%;
    padding: 5%;
  }
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="teambiowrap">     
    <h3>meet our team</h3>
    <div id="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/bioexample.png"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div id="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/chris.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div id="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/andy.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div id="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/tim.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div id="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/dave.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div id="teambio">
       <img class="bioimg" src="Images/jim.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div id="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/jess.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div id="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/amanda.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div id="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/victor.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, replace the `#teambio` with a `.teambio` class in your html and css. Then, repost your issue, if it still persists

Comment: @jesslouko `.bioimg{display:block; max-width:800px; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
<div class="teambiowrap">     
    <h3>meet our team</h3>
    <div class="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/bioexample.png"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div class="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/chris.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div class="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/andy.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div class="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/tim.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div class="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/dave.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div class="teambio">
       <img class="bioimg" src="Images/jim.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div class="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/jess.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div class="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/amanda.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div class="teambio">
        <img class="bioimg" src="Images/victor.jpg"><br><br><strong>NAME</strong> Position<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum sit amet tempor tellus. Nulla sed ligula in tellus eleifend ullamcorper. Nunc mi neque, interdum nec nulla id, hendrerit lacinia mi. Ut gravida libero ac tristique elementum. Nam tristique dui quis metus accumsan luctus. Vestibulum dictum.
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/respond.js"></script>
```

mediaqueries is not support same page IE browser. this time css extrenal file use but no change your css. Also, you should note that using respond.js could cause a delay in which you see the non-media query styles before the media query styles are parsed and applied. The recommendation is that you put respond.js in the header to avoid this as much as possible, although, it's also good to keep your js files in the footer so up to you.and use id replace in class.

respond js:https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/commit/4d60f45716b8395e6f24238f9dc5e34c857e87f2

Comment: Agree with the above and see this post that says the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407792/ie7-8-9-not-reading-media-query-properly?rq=1