# IE ignoring media queries

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries

I am having a hair raising problem with IE not listening to my media queries. I am using Bootstrap 3.1.1. The website works perfectly in FF and Chrome. However, all version of IE (including the latest v11, downloaded yesterday) are showing problems.

I have scoured the internet for answers, it seems nobody else is having this problem, therefore I've probably done something wrong.

To reproduce this problem, try opening this page in chrome and IE: http://jsfiddle.net/cre8ve/VaBVs/

This is the code:

HTML5:

```
<div class="monkey">
HAHOAOHOAA
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.monkey {
padding-top: 50px;
border-radius: 15px;
background: #333;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
.monkey {padding-top: 200px;}
}
```

..............

Try resizing the result window to ~900px. You will see that Chrome respects the media query but IE does not.

Comment: besides the point, but 'Canuse' is a great place to quickly check the support for a feature - http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Comment: It is working fine for me in IE11.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d6VM3/

Comment: Have you got IE set to a lower version in your dev tools ?

Comment: Are you triggering quirks mode in IE?  (hit f12 to find out)

Comment: `<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'/>` this will stop your visitors from using quirks too.

Comment: Also, in jsfiddle, you have to resize the preview window , not the full browser window. jsfidde runs in frames

Comment: IE is in "standard mode" not quirks mode. I'm using standard vanilla IE11, freshly installed. Turns out the browser is "zoomed in" 156% for some reason, if you zoom to 100% it fixes it...

Comment: Pete, can you send us a live link to test the actual site?

Comment: works for me, down to IE8 - and then jsfiddle itself breaks.

Comment: ^same for me @RobSedgwick

Comment: http://cre8veonline.com/wold/000.html is the actual site - you can see the padding-top of the element ".duperman" does not respect the media query on IE11

Comment: To mitigate hunting through all my code, you can see the .duperman div in the top right (where the facebook box is)... on chrome it moves down correctly with the padding-top changing to 120px. In IE it only listens to line 44 of CSS (padding-top: 40px) and media queries do not override it...

Comment: Looking at it in IE11 and IE10, I see more or less the same thing that I see in Chrome (with exception of some image and text-size differences.  I think you're media queries are working fine, something else is producing a result that you aren't expecting.  

I can see padding-top: of .duperman to change from 120px to 40px.

Comment: @Pete, didn't see the part where you mention the zoom setting you had on - glad it's sorted.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! A missing bracket after the media query was causing the other problems.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread here. You need to load respond js to get your media queries back in browsers that don't support them, and you might need to load conditional comments to detect ie and give it its own stylesheet with overrides to get it working right.

[IE7,8,9 not reading media query properly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407792/ie7-8-9-not-reading-media-query-properly?rq=1)